# Flutter web embed form using js

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart

I am trying to embed a form from https://convertkit.com/ending-a-business-relationship onto my flutter Webpage. This has been super difficult and I can't seem to figure out why there isn't some easy system like with flutter apps.

So far I have set it up like this:

```
class MyDesktopBody extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyDesktopBody({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final currentWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBarDesktop(),
      body: Center(
        child: Iframe(),
        // child: Text(
        //   "COMING SOON!",
        //   style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge,
        //   textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Iframe extends StatelessWidget {
  Iframe() {
    // ignore: undefined_prefixed_name
    ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory('iframe', (int viewId) {
      var iframe = html.IFrameElement();


      return iframe;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        width: 800, height: 600, child: HtmlElementView(viewType: 'iframe'));
  }
}
```

However this gives me the following error:

```
Refused to display 'https://app.convertkit.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.
```

I read people saying to add embed to it however this just leads to a 404 from the website. Is there really no simple way to embed a form from another site using js for flutter websites?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When using Flutter, you should probably use a webview widget such as [webviewx](https://pub.dev/packages/webviewx) instead of using `dart:html` and friends!

But that will probably not solve the actual error message, because it means that Convertkit forbids you to embed that URL in an `<iframe>`! You need to [check with Convertkit how to embed correctly](https://help.convertkit.com/en/articles/4009572-form-embedding-basics).

> SAMEORIGIN
>
> The page can only be displayed in a frame on the same origin as the page itself.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options